# How to Migrate django models to an MySQL read-only database?

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

I'm completely new to the Django development. In my work, My manager has given me a task of migrating the existing Models of my Django projects to a Read-only Database of MySQL server.

additional details - 
1) I have created a User in MySQL with read only privileges.

Kindly help me in solving this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question doesn't make sense. If the database is read-only, how will you create models in it? But in any case, shouldn't you be asking your manager for help rather than random people on the internet?

Comment: He wants to create the ORM models for an existing database, totally legit. That user he created is probably there so he can inspect database internals as manager can't provide any documentation for the database.